# How to display dynamic SVGs with several tags into React?

Tags: svg, xml-namespaces, reactjs

I'm trying to display a SVG with several tags inside my react website. Later on I want to exchange the svg contents and need functionality to rearrange their position, that is why I'm not using any other tool to handle static SVGs.

I'm facing several problems when adding the pure SVG code (*see below*) into my Component return statement:

1. **xmlns** tags causing a *TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function*
2. When removing **xmlns** tags: **defs** and **metadata** tags causing same error as in 1.
3. When removing problem tags from 2., the *style* attribute of **rect** causes trouble:

**Error**:
*The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX*

Is it just a formatting issue? Do I simply need to put a specific combination of Brackets around the style tag or is there a problem in parsing SVG-tags, since (maybe) the xmlns definitions are needed to tell the browser about valid svg tags?

**Info**: When placing a simple content (e.g. a circle) inside the svg, it works (without problematic tags defined in 1. and 2.).

Here's my sample SVG:

```
<svg
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    version="1.1"
    id="svg2"
    viewBox="0 0 545.71427 302.85714"
    height="85.473015mm"
    width="154.0127mm">
<defs id="defs4" />
<metadata id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
        <cc:Work rdf:about="">
            <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
            <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
            <dc:title></dc:title>
        </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(-137.14285,-118.07648)" id="layer1">
    <rect
        y="118.07648"
        x="137.14285"
        height="302.85715"
        width="545.71429"
        id="rect4147"
        style="opacity:1;fill:#00b3ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:35.43299866;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.20000005;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402542/embedding-svg-into-reactjs

Comment: Thanks. Just to keep all readers on track: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style
So the style attributes need to be parsed somehow.