# Turning an SVG string into an image in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, xss

I have a dynamically generated SVG string in a React component. I want to embed this as an image in the component. Currently, I'm using something along the lines of:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var image = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" width="47.4" height="40.65" viewBox="21 18.5 158 135.5"><path d="M25,50 l150,0 0,100 -150,0 z" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="rgb(128,224,255)" fill-opacity="1" ></path><path d="M25,50 L175,150 M25,150 L175,50" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="black" ></path><g transform="translate(0,0)" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="none" ><circle cx="100" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="70" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="130" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle></g></svg>';
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: image }} />
        )
    }
}
```

However using a property called `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` makes me pretty uneasy. Is there a more generally accepted (and safer) way to do this?

Comment: There is a good answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402542/embedding-svg-into-reactjs

Answer (score 50):

Since the SVG is dynamically generated and you can't store it as an asset, as an alternative to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you could simply set it as a `Data URI` on the image. So something like...

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const image = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" width="47.4" height="40.65" viewBox="21 18.5 158 135.5"><path d="M25,50 l150,0 0,100 -150,0 z" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="rgb(128,224,255)" fill-opacity="1" ></path><path d="M25,50 L175,150 M25,150 L175,50" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="black" ></path><g transform="translate(0,0)" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="none" ><circle cx="100" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="70" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="130" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle></g></svg>';
        return (
            <div>
              <img src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(image)}`} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

See post here: https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/

Comment: If you end up using this method you may need to wrap the SVG output in _encodeURIComponent():_ `<img src={\`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(image)}\` />`

Comment: The  code ```<img src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${image}` />``` is missing an `}` to close src property

Comment: This is not working with this svg `https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/jdenticon/:seed.svg` I tested in the `css-trick` too

Comment: @DavidYeiser `encodeURIComponent()` worked for me, thanks!!

Answer (score 15):

One thing you can do is to convert your svg string to base64 and then use it like this:

```
const image = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" width="47.4" height="40.65" viewBox="21 18.5 158 135.5"><path d="M25,50 l150,0 0,100 -150,0 z" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="rgb(128,224,255)" fill-opacity="1" ></path><path d="M25,50 L175,150 M25,150 L175,50" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="black" ></path><g transform="translate(0,0)" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="none" ><circle cx="100" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="70" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="130" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle></g></svg>';
const buff = new Buffer(image);
const base64data = buff.toString('base64');

return <img src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,${base64data }' alt="" />
```

if you don't want to use buffer, use this:

```
const base64data = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(image)));
```

Comment: This works with my case while `<img src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(image)}` />` doesn't. And my linter(in `@types/node`) says the btoa is deprecated. It's better to use `Buffer.from(unescape(encodeURIComponent(image)),"latin1").toString("base64");`

Comment: This `latin1` is not necessary here, although `btoa()` uses `latin1` instead of `utf8`.

Comment: This worked in my case. Thanks a lot ser

Comment: Perfect! way to go thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

Simply use this package: https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-inlinesvg

Example:

```
import SVG from 'react-inlinesvg';

...    

const mySVG = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg>';
return <SVG src={mySVG} />;
```

Answer (score 6):

### `React ref` with `innerHTML` works quite well and is clean.

```js
var image = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" width="47.4" height="40.65" viewBox="21 18.5 158 135.5"><path d="M25,50 l150,0 0,100 -150,0 z" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="rgb(128,224,255)" fill-opacity="1" ></path><path d="M25,50 L175,150 M25,150 L175,50" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="black" ></path><g transform="translate(0,0)" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="none" ><circle cx="100" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="70" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="130" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle></g></svg>';


const useApp = () => {
  const svgWrapperRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    svgWrapperRef.current.innerHTML = image;
  }, [])
  return {
    svgWrapperRef
  }
}
const App = () => {
  const {svgWrapperRef} = useApp()
  return (
    <div ref={svgWrapperRef}></div>
  )
}

const root = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Despite the attention it received, this is a great solution. No extra library and no unsafe HTML. Worth mentioning, useEffect is required here, otherwise ref.current will be undefined and your app will explode at runtime.

Comment: @CyberRobot can you please elaborate on the useEffect being required? I'm attempting to follow this solution as I need the SVG to be inline but my app IS in fact exploding at runtime. It seems to happen as soon as the function is called:
```
const createSVG = (svg) => {
    const svgWrapper = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      svgWrapper.current.innerHTML = svg;
    }, []);
    
    return { svgWrapper }
}```

Comment: In your case, the issue may be with the svg parameter as it is passed down to the function. It is possibly undefined at the time it is assigned to svgWrapper.current.innerHTML. A solution would be to add svg to the useEffect dependency array. Also, add a safeguard for svg inside useEffect so that an undefined value doesn't get assigned svgWrapper.current.innerHTML.

Answer (score 6):

In this way, I succeeded.

```js
const svgStr = "<svg></svg>";
const svg = new Blob([svgStr], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(svg);
```

```html
<img src={url} />
```

Answer (score -2):

*I know the question is about the `string` of an `svg` object, but in many cases you can use the `svg` object **directly** and even change it **dynamically**, which can be a cleaner approach in comparison to using string*.

---

Using the `svg` object **directly**:

```
import React from 'react';

function CustomSvgObject({ }) {
    return <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" width="47.4" height="40.65" viewBox="21 18.5 158 135.5"><path d="M25,50 l150,0 0,100 -150,0 z" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="rgb(128,224,255)" fill-opacity="1" ></path><path d="M25,50 L175,150 M25,150 L175,50" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="black" ></path><g transform="translate(0,0)" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="none" ><circle cx="100" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="70" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="130" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle></g></svg>
}
```

You can also **dynamically** change the `svg`, like the `className` property or the `color` of the `svg` elements:

```
import React from 'react';

function CustomSvgObject({ className, color }) {
    return <svg className={className} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" width="47.4" height="40.65" viewBox="21 18.5 158 135.5"><path d="M25,50 l150,0 0,100 -150,0 z" stroke-width="4" stroke={color} fill="rgb(128,224,255)" fill-opacity="1" ></path><path d="M25,50 L175,150 M25,150 L175,50" stroke-width="4" stroke={color} fill={color} ></path><g transform="translate(0,0)" stroke-width="4" stroke={color} fill="none" ><circle cx="100" cy="30" r="7.5" fill={color} ></circle><circle cx="70" cy="30" r="7.5" fill={color} ></circle><circle cx="130" cy="30" r="7.5" fill={color} ></circle></g></svg>
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I would store the svg image in a separate folder(`assets`), and import the image into the react component

Something like this:

SomeComponent.js:

```
import { SampleImage } from '../assets/SomeFile';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
              <img src={SampleImage} />
            <div/>
        )
    }
}
```

SomeFile.svg:

```
<?xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2"encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <svg baseProfile="tiny" width="47.4" height="40.65" viewBox="21 18.5 158 135.5"><path d="M25,50 l150,0 0,100 -150,0 z" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="rgb(128,224,255)" fill-opacity="1" ></path><path d="M25,50 L175,150 M25,150 L175,50" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="black" ></path><g transform="translate(0,0)" stroke-width="4" stroke="black" fill="none" ><circle cx="100" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="70" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" ></circle><circle cx="130" cy="30" r="7.5" fill="black" >
    </circle></g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: This is the normal way to work with svgs. I have a string and want to generate an element out of it. the strings come from server

Comment: Is it possible to set style on this dynamicaly render svg?