# React.createElement render a svg from String

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have an `svg` in a String variable. I get this string from an API call, so this information is dynamically present. I want to render this string via `React.createElement` dynamically on browser. How do I do this?

One way is to parse svg string into elements, then call `React.createElement(...)` for each element inside svg recursively, but writing an SVG parser doesn't seem to be optimal. Is there a cleaner way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:'<svg ....></svg>'}}/>`

Comment: How do I do this in react?

Comment: just copy the code into your component, replace the string with your svg string. @zookastos

Comment: The thing is, I am looking to render this svg element dynamically. So need to do it via React.createElement() method. Is it possible to do it via this way as well? Thanks.

Comment: I think, maybe this will solve the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900569/turning-an-svg-string-into-an-image-in-a-react-component

Comment: you can replace the string with any of your state or variable.