# Displaying raw SVG in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg

Hi there I'm getting an SVG from an api in this form:

```
<svg> ..... </svg>
```

I'm passing this svg as an props to this MainDisplay Component

```
class MainDispay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    donothing(props);
    super(props);
    console.log("props", this.props.Collections);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.props.Collections.map((DataObj, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            <div>{DataObj.name}</div>
            {this.props.Collections[i].DisplayProps.map((Data, j) => (
              <div key={j}>{Data.image_data}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Only problem is that the `Data.image_data` displays `<svg>.....<svg>` instead of an image.

Any idea how to display image instead. THANKS in ADVANCE

Comment: I found this answer and it works well for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900569/turning-an-svg-string-into-an-image-in-a-react-component

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reacts [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render any supplied html string:

```
<div key={j} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: Data.image_data}} />
```

**Be careful!** This attribute opens your app for vulnerable cross-site scripting attacks. Make sure to sanitize your `image_data` to strip any html other than `svg`. More on this e.g. in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1637573/9969672

Comment: I have to convert the string svg to base64 first

Comment: You’re right, for images this is an even better solution! Had only the „HTML“-part on my mind while answering…

Answer (score 1):

One effective way is to pass SVG as a source of 'img' tag.

```
<img key={j} src={Data.image_data} />
```