# React Vite - How to display a dynamic SVG without saving it as a .svg file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, vite

I get a SVG from an API call which looks something like this:

```
<svg width="848" height="848" viewBox="0 0 848 848" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">xxxxxxxxx</svg>
```

Now I would like to display this SVG in my react component **without** having to create a seperate .svg file for each of my SVGs as shown in the SVGR docs like: `import { ReactComponent as Ticket} from "./ticket.svg";`

How can this be achieved in React vite? (with or without SVGR), the `<img src={svg} />` method doesn't work for me either since it's a more complex SVG with some direct links/API calls

I am using the vite-plugin-svgr with:

**vite.config**

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svgr(), react()],
});
```

My component

```
const TicketDetail = () => {
  const [ticketSvg, setTicketSvg] = useState();

  const getTicketSVG = () => {
    // ...fetching SVG here

    setTicketSvg(svg); // looks something like <svg> xxxxxxxxxxx </svg>
  };

  return (
    <header className={styles.header}>
      // display svg here
      <svg>{ticketSvg}</svg>
    </header>
  );
};
```

Comment: Have you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900569/turning-an-svg-string-into-an-image-in-a-react-component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning an SVG string into an image in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900569/turning-an-svg-string-into-an-image-in-a-react-component)

Comment: These answers do not work since my SVG uses internal HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

If the SVG is interactive and/or otherwise complex, then you can put it in an iframe with the svg string being the **srcdoc** like this:

Given the recieved SVG...

```
var S='<svg width="848" height="848" viewBox="0 0 848 848" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">hello</svg>';
```

Then...

```
var I=document.createElement('iframe');

I.id='SvgHolder';

I.width=500;

I.height=300;

I.srcdoc=S;

document.body.appendChild(I);
```

Note: One can easily write a function to process multiple SVGs in this way, by passing X,Y,width, height and SVG string to it.

The beauty with an iframe is that you get to manage the security side of things.