# How can I display an SVG returned from an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a dynamic SVG which I've got as a return value from an API, this API contains several HTTP calls inside so I can't display it in a `<img src={svg} />` tag.

The SVG which I try to display can be found here: https://www.svgviewer.dev/s/g4PDWSVs

I use React Vite, with the SVGR plugin for Vite, when I copy the SVG data from the API, and store it as a file: ticket.svg, I am able to display it like this. **However I don't want to store it in a file before displaying it**, I want to directly display it in my JSX without manually having to make a .svg file for every SVG

Here is the code which I am currently using where I hardcoded ticket.svg as a file and display it as a React Component successfully, however my goal is to display the svg directly from the ticketSvg stored in state.

```
import { ReactComponent as Ticket } from "./../../assets/ticket.svg";

const TicketDetail = () => {
      const [ticketSvg, setTicketSvg] = useState();
    
      const getTicketSVG = () => {
        // ...fetching SVG here
    
        setTicketSvg(svg); // looks something like <svg> ...svgData here..</svg>
      };
    
      return (
        <header className={styles.header}>
          // display svg here
          <Ticket />
        </header>
      );
    };
```

I have also tried to use a  tag, but in this case only the frame of the SVG will be displayed but the HTTP calls in the SVG won't execute.

```
<img src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(ticketSvg)}`} />
```

Some of the resources I tried, but without result:

- [Turning an SVG string into an image in a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900569/turning-an-svg-string-into-an-image-in-a-react-component)
- [How to dynamically import SVG and render it inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339259/how-to-dynamically-import-svg-and-render-it-inline/61472427#61472427)
- [Unable to import SVG with Vite as ReactComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309561/unable-to-import-svg-with-vite-as-reactcomponent)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

1. Result for using `<img src={svg} />`

> ERROR: GET http://localhost:5174/ticket-detail/.....[HTTP/1.1 404 Not
> Found 1ms]

2. Result for using `` <img src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(ticketSvg)}`} /> ``

The images which should be retrieved from the API calls inside the SVG don't get executed, as you can see the QR code and logo's aren't being displayed.

[image]

Comment: maybe try setting initial value to ticketSvg as null and then do something like

{ticketSvg ? <img src={`data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${encodeURIComponent(ticketSvg)}`} /> : <></>}

Comment: The SVG contains a png image. You'll have to [convert that inner image to a data URL if you want the SVG itself to display as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903224/how-many-levels-of-recursion-does-svg-support).

Comment: @RobertLongson There is nothing wrong with the ticket.svg file, as I said: the solution where I am using a dedicated svg file for the SVG is working fine. But since I am getting the svg from an API I am unable to store the svg to a file and use it like that. I want to display it from the ticketSvg variable

Comment: As explained by @Robert Longson: **external references can't work** in an `<img>` tag - as proven by your last screenshot (based on a data URL). As an alternative you might try an `<object>` element – if injecting the svg isn't an option.