# How to place svg file unflataned on React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, components

I am trying to embbed svg file on react component but it attaches as flattaned. Is there any way to post it as pure svg.

please see the where its posted
https://abk-react-portfolio.herokuapp.com/

and how its supposted to view like

https://abk-react-portfolio.herokuapp.com/static/media/wordcloud_ahmet.445abff9.svg

i used like this way

import WordCloud from '../assets/images/landing/wordcloud_ahmet.svg';

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, u can inline simple svg, but u will have to convert all the style attributes inside svg into JSX type styles attributes, class to classNames.

This can be done for smaller svg file

Here is codepen example [Inline SVG](https://codepen.io/acusti/pen/qNWMGL?editors=0010),

```
    function SvgWithXlink (props) {
    return (
        <svg
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        >
            <style>
                { `.classA { fill:${props.fill} }` }
            </style>
            <defs>
                <g id="Port">
                    <circle style={{fill:'inherit'}} r="10"/>
                </g>
            </defs>

            <text y="15">black</text>
            <use x="70" y="10" xlinkHref="#Port" />
            <text y="35">{ props.fill }</text>
            <use x="70" y="30" xlinkHref="#Port" className="classA"/>
            <text y="55">blue</text>
            <use x="70" y="50" xlinkHref="#Port" style={{fill:'blue'}}/>
        </svg>
    );
}


ReactDOM.render(<SvgWithXlink fill="violet" />, document.querySelector('body > div'));
```

Also refer this question for more info [embedding-svg-into-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402542/embedding-svg-into-reactjs)

Since ur svg file is very big file, it would be better to flatten it,

If u import it by flattening it, It will also be easier to edit it in future, if u want to change something, by just importing it in any svg editor.

However, if u convert it into JSX style, it cannot be imported into any SVG editor