# SyntaxError: unknown: Namespace tags are not supported by default

Tags: reactjs, svg

I get the following error when trying to download svg as a React Component.

> SyntaxError: unknown: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can turn on the 'throwIfNamespace' flag to bypass this warning.

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as LO } from "../a/Logo.svg"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Logo = () => (
  <>
    <NavLink to={"/"}>
     <LO width={"40px"} height={"40px"} />
    </NavLink>
  </>
);

export default Logo;
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: what is this 2nd import, is that the way to import ??

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Comment: Your SVG contains namespace tags in its metadata. You can remove them.

Comment: @Jesus Please refer to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402542/embedding-svg-into-reactjs?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding SVG into ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23402542/embedding-svg-into-reactjs)

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, then namespaces are not supported.

Comment: Manually changing svg attributes into camelcase is cumbersome. Do it here https://svg2jsx.com/

Answer (score 332, accepted):

In the SVG file, **try changing:**

```html
sketch:type TO sketchType
xmlns:xlink TO xmlnsXlink
xlink:href  TO xlinkHref
xmlns:bx    TO xmlnsBx
bx:origin   TO bxOrigin
etc...
```

The idea is to create a camelCase property, remember that you are working with JSX, you are not creating a string as XML does.

Comment: So ... we have to use JSX-friendly SVGs now? Seems a bit ridiculous...

Comment: THANK YOU! This is the answer that keeps on giving. I am using Vectornator to create my SVG files and it outputs a lot of `vectornator:layerName` So, I went through and every time I found a colon that wasn't in a URL, but was naming something, I changed it to camelCase (like `vectornatorLayerName`) and the SVG works now!  Thank you @Frawel

Comment: I don't understand the need to rewrite the SVG file settings to work wit JSX. I can use SVG files created in Python, view them through Django in html then view the same SVG files in TypeScript in Angular. Why can't the React people build converters for this?

Answer (score 46):

Since we are in the JSX playground your SVG tags should be written as camelCase

So you can easily optimize your SVG using the link below to avoid this error :)

[svgminify](https://www.svgminify.com)

Comment: The link is down. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @Nulldroid
yup try this one: https://www.svgminify.com

Comment: This site does not convert the tags to camelCase.

Comment: This site also removes any IDs you might have set. Use https://svg2jsx.com/ -- perfect tool!

Answer (score 15):

The most simple solution is to just convert the SVG file to JSX.Then create a separate component or just copy paste the  tag. This website does the job perfectly.

https://svg2jsx.com/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you tharusha, this is the winning answer for me!

[svgminify](https://www.svgminify.com) did not fix the root issue: React throwing a wobbler at namespaces.

Comment: Not recommend! Tested 3 svgs and all of them had issues after this converter...

Answer (score 5):

This is a nice tool that converts an SVG into a react friendly component and includes support for typescript

https://react-svgr.com/playground/

Answer (score 5):

In mine I had to change:

```
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

to

```
   xmlnsSvg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Another option is to remove the xmlns:svg property with its value.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) to compress your SVG files. Simple CLI tool that runs with NodeJS and doesn't require you to upload your copyrighted SVGs anywhere.

Comment: Presumably that could be run automatically as part of the build. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with all my svg files. Opening them in Adobe Illustrator and saving them again solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) - it's a command-line tool that automatically strips out the offending tags.

`npm install -g svgo`

`svgo *.svg`

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert the SVG file to JSX then use it. Use https://svg2jsx.com/