# How to render svg icons in react

Tags: reactjs, svg

```
var filled_lock = ' <svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 15 15" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><!-- Generator: Sketch 48.1 (47250) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch --><title>Locked</title><desc>Created with Sketch.</desc><defs></defs><g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Icon/Locked/Filled/Light"><rect id="Rectangle" fill="#D8D8D8" opacity="0" x="-1" y="-1" width="15" height="15"></rect><g id="Icon/Locked/Filled/Dark" transform="translate(-1.000000, -1.000000)"><rect id="Rectangle" fill="#D8D8D8" opacity="0" x="0" y="0" width="15" height="15"></rect><g transform="translate(3.000000, 1.000000)" fill="#668cb3"><path d="M7.75,5.5 L2.25,5.5 L2.25,3.25 C2.25,1.73365625 3.483875,0.5 5.0005,0.5 C6.51659375,0.5 7.75,1.73365625 7.75,3.25 L7.75,5.5 Z M5.25,9.4685 L5.25,10.5 L4.75,10.5 L4.75,9.4685 C4.3186875,9.35746875 4,8.9659375 4,8.5 C4,7.94771875 4.44771875,7.5 5,7.5 C5.55228125,7.5 6,7.94771875 6,8.5 C6,8.9659375 5.6813125,9.35746875 5.25,9.4685 Z M8.25,5.5 L8.25,3.25 C8.25,1.4553125 6.7949375,0 5.0005,0 C3.2050625,0 1.75,1.4553125 1.75,3.25 L1.75,5.5 L0,5.5 L0,13 L10,13 L10,5.5 L8.25,5.5 Z" id="Fill-1"></path><path d="M5,8 C4.7243125,8 4.5,8.2243125 4.5,8.5 C4.5,8.7756875 4.7243125,9 5,9 C5.2756875,9 5.5,8.7756875 5.5,8.5 C5.5,8.2243125 5.2756875,8 5,8" id="Fill-3"></path></g></g></g></g></svg> ';
```

This var filled_lock is my svg icon which Im trying to render in a div but it's not showing it up

I tried putting it in `<img src={filled_lock} />` still it doesn't show up

I tried `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:{filled_lock}}} />` still no success

Does anyone know how we can render it in react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So investigating it further I saw that using quotes in the filled_lock was showing the string itself. On removing the string it was failing due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820954/syntaxerror-unknown-namespace-tags-are-not-supported-by-default) reason. Which when I fixed gave me the desired output

New code

```
var filled_lock = <svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 15 15" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><!-- Generator: Sketch 48.1 (47250) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch --><title>Locked</title><desc>Created with Sketch.</desc><defs></defs><g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Icon/Locked/Filled/Light"><rect id="Rectangle" fill="#D8D8D8" opacity="0" x="-1" y="-1" width="15" height="15"></rect><g id="Icon/Locked/Filled/Dark" transform="translate(-1.000000, -1.000000)"><rect id="Rectangle" fill="#D8D8D8" opacity="0" x="0" y="0" width="15" height="15"></rect><g transform="translate(3.000000, 1.000000)" fill="#668cb3"><path d="M7.75,5.5 L2.25,5.5 L2.25,3.25 C2.25,1.73365625 3.483875,0.5 5.0005,0.5 C6.51659375,0.5 7.75,1.73365625 7.75,3.25 L7.75,5.5 Z M5.25,9.4685 L5.25,10.5 L4.75,10.5 L4.75,9.4685 C4.3186875,9.35746875 4,8.9659375 4,8.5 C4,7.94771875 4.44771875,7.5 5,7.5 C5.55228125,7.5 6,7.94771875 6,8.5 C6,8.9659375 5.6813125,9.35746875 5.25,9.4685 Z M8.25,5.5 L8.25,3.25 C8.25,1.4553125 6.7949375,0 5.0005,0 C3.2050625,0 1.75,1.4553125 1.75,3.25 L1.75,5.5 L0,5.5 L0,13 L10,13 L10,5.5 L8.25,5.5 Z" id="Fill-1"></path><path d="M5,8 C4.7243125,8 4.5,8.2243125 4.5,8.5 C4.5,8.7756875 4.7243125,9 5,9 C5.2756875,9 5.5,8.7756875 5.5,8.5 C5.5,8.2243125 5.2756875,8 5,8" id="Fill-3"></path></g></g></g></g></svg>;
```

For output:

```
<div>{filled_lock}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-svg` for this:

```
import { ReactSVG } from 'react-svg';

<ReactSVG src={filled_lock} />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save svg image in an `*.svg` file and import it as:

```
import filled_lock from './filled_lock.svg';
function App() {
  return (
    <img src={filled_lock} alt="filled_lock" />
  );
}
```

Or

```
import { ReactComponent as FilledLock } from './filled_lock.svg';
function App() {
  return (
    <FilledLock />
  );
}
```

[Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)