# Embed Google SVG icon failed: Namespace tags are not supported by default

Tags: html, reactjs, image, svg, jsx

I am trying to embed the Google Icon as SVG file specified in [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines). I include the local path as source for the `img` element:

```
<img src={GoogleLogo} className={SignInPageStyle.GoogleLogo}/>
```

I then got this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: unknown: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.
```

Here is how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="46px" height="46px" viewBox="0 0 46 46" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.3.3 (12081) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>btn_google_dark_normal_ios</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs>
        <filter x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="filter-1">
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.168 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feColorMatrix>
            <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter2"></feOffset>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0.5" in="shadowOffsetOuter2" result="shadowBlurOuter2"></feGaussianBlur>
            <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0.084 0" in="shadowBlurOuter2" type="matrix" result="shadowMatrixOuter2"></feColorMatrix>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter1"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="shadowMatrixOuter2"></feMergeNode>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
            </feMerge>
        </filter>
        <rect id="path-2" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" rx="2"></rect>
        <rect id="path-3" x="5" y="5" width="38" height="38" rx="1"></rect>
    </defs>
    <g id="Google-Button" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="9-PATCH" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-608.000000, -219.000000)"></g>
        <g id="btn_google_dark_normal" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-1.000000, -1.000000)">
            <g id="button" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(4.000000, 4.000000)" filter="url(#filter-1)">
                <g id="button-bg">
                    <use fill="#4285F4" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                    <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                    <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                    <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g id="button-bg-copy">
                <use fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                <use fill="none" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
            </g>
            <g id="logo_googleg_48dp" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(15.000000, 15.000000)">
                <path d="M17.64,9.20454545 C17.64,8.56636364 17.5827273,7.95272727 17.4763636,7.36363636 L9,7.36363636 L9,10.845 L13.8436364,10.845 C13.635,11.97 13.0009091,12.9231818 12.0477273,13.5613636 L12.0477273,15.8195455 L14.9563636,15.8195455 C16.6581818,14.2527273 17.64,11.9454545 17.64,9.20454545 L17.64,9.20454545 Z" id="Shape" fill="#4285F4" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M9,18 C11.43,18 13.4672727,17.1940909 14.9563636,15.8195455 L12.0477273,13.5613636 C11.2418182,14.1013636 10.2109091,14.4204545 9,14.4204545 C6.65590909,14.4204545 4.67181818,12.8372727 3.96409091,10.71 L0.957272727,10.71 L0.957272727,13.0418182 C2.43818182,15.9831818 5.48181818,18 9,18 L9,18 Z" id="Shape" fill="#34A853" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M3.96409091,10.71 C3.78409091,10.17 3.68181818,9.59318182 3.68181818,9 C3.68181818,8.40681818 3.78409091,7.83 3.96409091,7.29 L3.96409091,4.95818182 L0.957272727,4.95818182 C0.347727273,6.17318182 0,7.54772727 0,9 C0,10.4522727 0.347727273,11.8268182 0.957272727,13.0418182 L3.96409091,10.71 L3.96409091,10.71 Z" id="Shape" fill="#FBBC05" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M9,3.57954545 C10.3213636,3.57954545 11.5077273,4.03363636 12.4404545,4.92545455 L15.0218182,2.34409091 C13.4631818,0.891818182 11.4259091,0 9,0 C5.48181818,0 2.43818182,2.01681818 0.957272727,4.95818182 L3.96409091,7.29 C4.67181818,5.16272727 6.65590909,3.57954545 9,3.57954545 L9,3.57954545 Z" id="Shape" fill="#EA4335" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                <path d="M0,0 L18,0 L18,18 L0,18 L0,0 Z" id="Shape" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
            </g>
            <g id="handles_square" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup"></g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820954/syntaxerror-unknown-namespace-tags-are-not-supported-by-default?rq=1) and tried by using camelCase and it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I solved the problem by replacing

`sketch:type`, `xmlns:xlink`, `xlink:href` AND `xmlns: sketch` all to camelCase:

`sketchType`, `xmlnsXlink`, `xlinkHref` AND `xmlnsSketch`.

If you have the same problem try replacing ALL `name: property` tags to camelCase.