# I can't SVG file open in react.js . Svg File Include CSS And Html file separate

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

i downloaded SVG Files from [Stroyset](https://storyset.com/), this website svg files like below link
[Here is the SVG Link](https://storyset.com/illustration/desktop-computer/bro/animate?share=73749) when you click Export button you get three option  like this [image] if i click download button i download svg format, this file can open in local browser i can't  in react app why?

when going like with image tag it showing error.
**who can i open this file in react.js**

Answer (score 0):

import svg file as you would import a .jpg file and then use it directly as a img tag's src for example:

```
import IconSvg from './path-to-svg-file.svg';
...
<img src={IconSvg} alt='icon' />
```

Comment: I trayed. but not working.......... sir

Comment: @MallikarjunMathapati whats the error?

Comment: like this sir :    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: unknown file: Namespace tags are not supported by default. React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.
   5 |   ...props
   6 | }, svgRef) {
>  7 |   return <svg className="animated" id="freepik_stories-desktop-computer" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" ref={svgRef} aria-labelledby={titleId} {...props}>

Comment: This question's answer should solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820954/syntaxerror-unknown-namespace-tags-are-not-supported-by-default

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vite (which most of the people do), you need a plugin to import the .svg and use it as a React Component.

just run

```
npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-svgr
```

If you are using TypeScript, there is also a declaration helper for better type inference:

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

// vite.config.js

```
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [...otherplugins, svgr({ include: '**/*.svg'})],
};
```

Then your beautiful svg files can be imported as

```
import Logo from "./logo.svg";

function SvgPreview(){
   return <Logo/>;
 }
```

Comment: you have any examples please pervade me sir..